# Can a component 'listen' for URL changes?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a dynamic navigation that matches the functionality in the below image. I've a bunch of links and am currently not using the `RouterLinkActive` functionality built into `Angular`. Instead, when each link is clicked I'm looping over all the items, removing the 'active' class and applying it to the newly clicked link.

This works fine, except when a link is clicked outside of the navigation. For example, if you imagine I'm in 'Sub Link 1' as shown in that image, and on the page is a link back to the homepage.

When the user clicks that link, they get taken to the homepage but the navigation doesn't update because it's already rendered and doesn't know about the `URL` change.

**So, first question - can the nav component 'listen' to the `URL` and update when it changes?**

If that's not possible, then maybe I can use the `RouterLinkActive` directive but currently it's causing me problems.

In the image below you'll see Second Link - it triggers the sub items to appear BUT (and this is important) that link doesn't actually navigate anywhere, it just makes the sub items appear. Because it doesn't have a route associated with it, I can't manage to get the `RouterLinkActive` to apply the 'active' class to it.

I've tried multiple different ways but nothing seems to work. If I assign it a route then it tries to navigate to a component (I have to add a component to the route array when defining the route item). I don't want a blank page to render or anything, just when 'Second link' is clicked, the 'active' class is applied and the sub items appear.

If I can get `RouterLinkActive` to work then the problems are solved because the `Angular` takes care of watching the route changes and applying the 'active' class itself.

**Second question: Given the fact that this is a dynamically generated nav, is there any way of getting routelinkactive to apply to links like 'second link' when they don't actually have a route associated with them?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to Router.events of the `RouterEvent class` as it is an observable and will emit navigation event data such as `NavigationEnd` `NavigationStart`, each of these classes exposes the url as well.

E.g

```
      router.events.subscribe( (event: Event) => {

        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
            // Do something on start
        }

        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            // Do something on end
        }

        if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
            // Do something on error
        }
    });
```

Comment: I will try this, thank you. Any ideas about the routeLinkActive where a route is null or empty? That would be the ideal solution as then I could hand off the application of classes etc to the framework and not worry about issues.

Comment: If you post the routerLink code you have, I might have something. It's very hard to tell since you haven't posted any code. Although, I would say that the 'active' side of routerLinkActive is css class based, so there must be actual links to work with.